# dojo.image.Gallery does not work with addOnLoad?

Tags: dojo

This is really weired, I'm trying to use dojo.image.Gallery, but when I require the dojox.image.Gallery, the dojo.addOnLoad() does not fire, however if i comment the line which require dojo.image.Gallery, i can see 'onload' in the console, code is like below

anything i missed?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Testing the Image Gallery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require('dojox.image.Gallery');
dojo.require('dojox.data.FlickrRestStore');
dojo.require("dojo.parser"); // find widgets
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
console.log('onload');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="testTitle">dojox.image.Gallery</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do have this same problem. After some effort, I happened to find out that with the full version dojo-release-1.7.2-src, it WORKS. Does it have anything to do with javascript compression? Kindly share if any one happens to know why...